# How to solve UnknownSessionException thrown in logout method in Apache Shiro?

Tags: java, apache, maven, logout, shiro

Good afternoon guys! I have a project in JSF that uses Apache Shiro Authentication. The login method works fine, but the logout method throw UnknownSessionException.

Here is my dependencies on pom.xml(Maven):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

StackTrace:

```
abr 07, 2017 9:20:26 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
GRAVE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id [e3b18152-09c3-4644-8815-f3bf7dd77513]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpSession.getAttribute(ShiroHttpSession.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:61)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.getResponseEncoding(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1310)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1198)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:405)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id [e3b18152-09c3-4644-8815-f3bf7dd77513]
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.AbstractSessionDAO.readSession(AbstractSessionDAO.java:170)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSessionManager.java:236)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSession(DefaultSessionManager.java:222)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager.doGetSession(AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupRequiredSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:152)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.getAttribute(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:249)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DelegatingSession.getAttribute(DelegatingSession.java:141)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.ProxiedSession.getAttribute(ProxiedSession.java:121)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpSession.getAttribute(ShiroHttpSession.java:131)
    ... 49 more
```

Shiro.ini:

```
# =======================
# Shiro INI configuration
# =======================

[main]

# =============================== 
# =============================== 
# Session Manager SHIRO NATIVE (WEB) 
# =============================== 
# =============================== 

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager 
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager 
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 3600000

shiro.loginUrl = /faces/paginalogin.xhtml
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher

# ===============================
# ===============================
# DATABASE SQL
# ===============================
# ===============================
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = false
jdbcRealm.authenticationCachingEnabled = false
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT senha FROM usuario WHERE email = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT if(nivel='A','admin','normal') FROM usuario WHERE email = ?


# ===============================
# MySQL
# ===============================
dbs=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
#dbs.driverClass = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dbs.user=root
dbs.databaseName=shiroexemplo
dbs.serverName=localhost
dbs.portNumber=3306


# ===============================
# ===============================
# DATABASE INSTANCE
# ===============================
# ===============================
jdbcRealm.dataSource=$dbs

[users]
# The 'users' section is for simple deployments
# when you only need a small number of statically-defined
# set of User accounts.

[roles]
admin=*
normal=*

[urls]
/faces/admin/*= authc, roles[admin]
/faces/normal/*=authc, roles[normal]
/faces/paginalogin.xhtml = anon
```

Java class:

```
package com.mycompany.shiroexemplo.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.SimpleHash;
import org.apache.shiro.session.Session;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.mycompany.shiroexemplo.dao.UsuarioDAO;
import com.mycompany.shiroexemplo.model.Usuario;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username;
    private String senha;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public Usuario usuario;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    public String autenticate() {

        SimpleHash hash = new SimpleHash("md5", senha);
        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, hash.toHex());

        token.setRememberMe(true);
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        log.info("logando usando o email [" + username + "] e senha [" + hash.toHex() + "]");

        try {
            if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
                currentUser.login(token);

                UsuarioDAO ud = new UsuarioDAO();
                usuario = ud.getUsuario(username);
            }

            if (currentUser.hasRole("admin")) {
                return "Admin";
            } else {
                return "Normal";
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro: ", "Usuário ou senha incorretos"));
            return "paginalogin";
        }

    }

    public String logout(ActionEvent ev) {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        try {
            if(currentUser.isAuthenticated()){
                currentUser.logout();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro: ", e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
        return "paginalogin";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you issue a redirect after logout? It's been a while since I've done anything with Faces, so I'm not sure of the request flow that you are seeing.  Basically, you would want the logout request to be the *last* thing to happen before a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer me. Doing some researches, I could solve the problem. First, I commented these lines in my Shiro.ini:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager 
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager 
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 3600000
```

After that, I implemented javax.servlet.http.HttpSession to get the current session, like this:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
```

Finally, I did a session.invalidate() and also a redirect in the page, like this:

```
session.invalidate();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext.redirect("faces/paginaLogin.xhtml");
```

The final version of logout method :

```
  public void logout(){
        try{
          Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
          HttpSession session=(HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
          if(currentUser.isAuthenticated()){
              session.invalidate();
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("faces/paginalogin.xhtml"); 

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro: ", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```